# Storing a block with a parameter inside a NSArray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I know I can define a property like a block, something like:

```
self.myProperty = ^(){
   // bla bla bla        
};
```

store that on an array doing

```
NSArray *arrayOfBlocks = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:[self.myProperty copy]];
```

and then execute it using

```
void (^ myblock)() = [arrayOfBlocks objectAtIndex:0];
myblock();
```

but what about if the block has a parameter?

I mean, a block like this one:

```
self.myProperty = ^(id myObject){
   // bla bla bla        
};
```

What I want is being able to keep this lines unchanged

```
void (^ myblock)() = [arrayOfBlocks objectAtIndex:0];
myblock();

// yes, I know I can replace myblock(); with myblock(object);
// but because I have a large number of blocks on this array, I will have to build
// a huge if if if if statements to see what block is being run and change the objects passed
```

What I want is to store the block with the parameter on the array... something like this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfBlocks = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:[self.myProperty(object?) copy]];
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, blocks are first-class values. You can make a factory method that returns a block which will be invoked with a certain object.

```
typedef void (^CallbackBlock)(void);
- (CallbackBlock)callbackWithNumber:(int)n
{
    return [^{
        NSLog(@"Block called with %d", n);
    } copy];
}
```

Usage:

```
[mutableArray addObject:[self callbackWithNumber:42]];
[mutableArray addObject:[self callbackWithNumber:1337]];

// later:
CallbackBlock cb = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
cb();
```

Comment: very clever idea to encapsulate the parameter and the block. This is black magic! Thanks!

Comment: @RubberDuck Welcome. Yes, this is something very neat, I pretty much love closures ;)

Comment: Hi @H2CO3

Isn't there a memory management issue when you send copy to the block before returning it from callbackWithNumber: ?

The block is added to the array, but it never gets released! Is copy really necessary in this case?

Comment: Bad answer; the above code did not solve the problem. n is lost unless the block is called within the same scope as a value for n was supplied. If you retrieve the block from the array from any other method, the app will crash.